# Como embaralhar caracteres de uma String em Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-10

Teria alguma função para *embaralhar* em **Delphi** para embaralhar uma `string`.

- Ex de String  := 'casa de madeira';
- Ex de retorno := 'medr ci saedaaa';

Comment: Da uma olhada se te ajuda https://www.clubedohardware.com.br/forums/topic/567952-embaralhar-letras/

Comment: Isso mesmo. Para não ficar sem resposta posso por o código com a resposta? ou você coloca... vai que o site sai do ar...

Comment: Se resolveu pode pôr o código pra ajudar o pessoal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postando para não ficar sem resposta como sugestão do Autor da pergunta.

Fonte: Jefferson Rudolf (users/34982)

```
function EmbaralharString(const aString: string): string;
var
  i: integer;
  vPosicao: integer;
  vLista: TStrings;
begin
  Randomize;

  vLista := TStringList.Create;

  for i := 1 to aString.Length do
    vLista.Add(aString[i]);

  for i := 1 to aString.Length do
  begin
    vPosicao := Random(vLista.Count);
    Result := Result + vLista.Strings[vPosicao];
    vLista.Delete(vPosicao);
  end;

  FreeAndNil(vLista);
end;
```

Bem simples, primeiro ele desmonta a string em e cria uma lista de "char", depois randomicamente pega cada "char" e monta uma nova string.